# Creating html button link - not working

Tags: javascript, html, django, templates, button

very quick question. I have a href link like so in my template.

```
<a href={% url tiptop.views.client_items name.pk %}>add item</a>
```

This works But if I wanted it to create it as a button for some reason it does not work.

```
<input type="button" on_click="window.location.href='{% url tiptop.views.client_items name.pk %}></a>'" value="Add item">
```

I don't understand why it does not work. Basically, the button shows, but when I click on the button it does NOTHING.

Comment: javascript "on click" event is `onclick` and not `on_click`, maybe thats why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
   <a <!--...your link code here -->
   <input type="button" onClick="window.location.href='{% url tiptop.views.client_items name.pk %}'" value="Add item"/></a>
```

Your Quotes the single and the double one where not closed properly.

Comment: Ok your right. And actually What andre matos said was correct too. Infact that was the real answer. Thanks to the both of you.